# How can I run the Jenkins jobs through terminal?

Tags: jenkins, terminal

I heard an version that webhooks could be used for this.
Please help)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are few ways to trigger a Jenkins build from command line:

1. [Remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) is offered in a REST-like style:

- Job without parameters:

  ```
       curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build --user username:token
  ```
- Job with parameters:

  ```
       curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/build \
       --user username:token \
       --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"id", "value":"123"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
  OR
       curl -X POST JENKINS_URL/job/JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters/id=123&verbosity=high \
       --user username:token
  ```

2. [Jenkins CLI](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI) - a built-in command line client that allows you to access Jenkins from a script or from your shell:

   ```
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s JENKINS_URL/ build JOB_NAME -w
      OR
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s JENKINS_URL/ build "folder1/folder2/JOB_NAME" -s
   ```
3. Wrappers: [Ruby](https://github.com/arangamani/jenkins_api_client), [Python](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), [Java](https://github.com/RisingOak/jenkins-client), [Javascript](https://github.com/jansepar/node-jenkins-api) etc. You can write a simple program to perform Jenkins build with your favorite language.

Comment: I did not try this but a Jenkins developer has a project that runs the Jenkins WAR file against his `Jenkinsfile`.  https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkinsfile-runner

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really precise...

But to launch a job with the terminal, here is solution with Curl:

```
curl "http://JENKINS_HOST/job/MY_JOB_NAME/build"
```